# Error while converting categorical feature to numerical feature in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

My dataframe contains a categorical feature 'Street' which can take 1 of the 2 possible values 'Grvl' or 'Pave'. I am trying to convert this categorical feature in to numerical value before fitting ML algorithm. My code looks like this

```
dataset['Street']=dataset['Street'].map({'Grvl':0,'Pave':1}).astype(int)
```

I have filled missing values with the most occurring value in the dataframe

```
dataset['Street'].isnull().sum()
```

I am getting following error

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-86f0b031335a> in <module>()
      2     print dataset['Street'].isnull().sum()
      3     #dataset['MSZoning'] = dataset['MSZoning'].map( {'A': 0, 'C': 1,'FV': 2,'I':3,'RH':4,'RL':5,'RP':6,'RM':7} ).astype(int)
----> 4     dataset['Street']=dataset['Street'].map({'Grvl':0,'Pave':1}).astype(int)
      5     dataset['LotShape']=dataset['LotShape'].map({'Reg':0,'IR1':1,'IR2':2,'IR3':3}).astype(int)
      6     dataset['LandContour']=dataset['LandContour'].map({'Lvl':0,'Bnk':1,'HLS':2,'Low':3}).astype(int)

C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in astype(self, dtype, copy, raise_on_error, **kwargs)
   2948 
   2949         mgr = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy,
-> 2950                                 raise_on_error=raise_on_error, **kwargs)
   2951         return self._constructor(mgr).__finalize__(self)
   2952 

C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in astype(self, dtype, **kwargs)
   2936 
   2937     def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
-> 2938         return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
   2939 
   2940     def convert(self, **kwargs):

C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, raw, **kwargs)
   2888 
   2889             kwargs['mgr'] = self
-> 2890             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
   2891             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
   2892 

C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in astype(self, dtype, copy, raise_on_error, values, **kwargs)
    432                **kwargs):
    433         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, raise_on_error=raise_on_error,
--> 434                             values=values, **kwargs)
    435 
    436     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, raise_on_error=True, values=None,

C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in _astype(self, dtype, copy, raise_on_error, values, klass, mgr, **kwargs)
    475 
    476                 # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
--> 477                 values = com._astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
    478                 values = values.reshape(self.shape)
    479 

C:\Users\JAYASHREE\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.pyc in _astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy)
   1912 
   1913         if np.isnan(arr).any():
-> 1914             raise ValueError('Cannot convert NA to integer')
   1915     elif arr.dtype == np.object_ and np.issubdtype(dtype.type, np.integer):
   1916         # work around NumPy brokenness, #1987

ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer
```

Comment: "I have filled missing values with the most occurring value in the dataframe"
I don't see such code here. Where is it?

Comment: I'm sure there's something in your `Street` column that's neither "Grvl" or "Pave". What's the output of `dataset['Street'].unique()`?

Comment: @CrazyElf Here's the code freq_street = dataset.Street.dropna().mode()[0]
dataset['Street']=dataset['Street'].fillna(freq_street)

Comment: @Bonifacio2  The output of statement is ['Pave' 'Grvl']

Comment: Your code should work.

Comment: @CrazyElf I found that the problem is with .astype(int).If I remove that it is working fine.Can you please suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You have NaN values in your dataframe ! Since You cannot convert series from object to integer (using asType(int)) if there are missing values you should fill missing values before !
`dataset['Street'].isnull().sum()` dosn't fill missing values

you can do it using [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) or [sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html)

Comment: I filled using mode value freq_street = dataset.Street.dropna().mode()[0] dataset['Street']=dataset['Street'].fillna(freq_street)

Comment: Show us bigger part of code, it's should work, but you tell is not.